# Elliptic-curve cryptography (ECC) in JS

Tags: reactjs, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am using following code to encrypt data **using ECC in JS.** I don't know how to **decrypt** this encrypted data. Can anyone help me out?

**Installation**

`npm install elliptic-curve`

**Importing the secp256k1 module**:

`var secp256k1 = require('elliptic-curve').secp256k1`

**Private to Public Key Conversion**:

`var privateKey = '278a5de700e29faae8e40e366ec5012b5ec63d36ec77e8a2417154cc1d25383f'`

`secp256k1.getPublicKey(privateKey)`

`'03fdd57adec3d438ea237fe46b33ee1e016eda6b585c3e27ea66686c2ea5358479'`

**Message Signing**:

`var message = "Hello, world!"`

`secp256k1.signMessage(message, privateKey)`

`'3046022100997b6210d959e67ad9cee01589d01daf0fe77ce0f002d040d769171c33504860022100e'`

Comment: This package is broken you can check the loadPublicKey method instead of returning secp256k1.ellipticCurve.keyFromPublic(rawPublicKey, 'hex') it returns secp256k1.keyFromPublic(rawPublicKey, 'hex') so the verifyHash method is broken as well

Comment: I have added the snippet in answer you can check it

Comment: The code you used is for [signing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) not encrypting so my code is for verifying signature rather than decrypting

Comment: thank you @GirishSrivatsa, can you provide the code to encrypt and decrypt my data using ecc?

Comment: I would suggest creating a symmetric key by ecc and using AES to encrypt/decrypt

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa why shouldn't i encrypt and decrypt my data using ECC instead AES? whats the differences?

Comment: I am unable to find schemes that solely rely on ecc for encryption most rely on a symmetric key derivation with encryption if you find any other type you can post here

Answer (score 0):

The package elliptic curve is broken here if you look at its source code this is just a wrapper for elliptic,A direct implementation based on elliptic is with no sanitisation for private key size and public key format(hex):

```
var EC = require('elliptic').ec
var curve = new EC('secp256k1')
var privateKey = '278a5de700e29faae8e40e366ec5012b5ec63d36ec77e8a2417154cc1d25383f'
var publicKey = curve.keyFromPrivate(privateKey).getPublic(true,"hex")
var message = "Hello, world!"
var signed = curve.sign(message, privateKey)
var publicKeyObject = curve.keyFromPublic(publicKey,"hex")
var check = publicKeyObject.verify(message, signed)
console.log(check)
```

Check running at [this](http://runkit.com/eragon-saphira/runkit-npm-elliptic-sign)